# Battery being guzzled, and drained faster than Windows OS, by alot

Tags: 11.10, intel, power-management

11.10, has it been tested with Sandy Bridge processors? I'm asking this, mainly have no idea why my computer under Ubuntu lasts only 2 hours (screen closed) but when under Windows 7 Home, it lasts approx 4 hours (screen on, LED SCREEN). (And my lap is hot running Ubuntu.)

Computer is a Samsung-laptop  Model: NP700Z5B-W01UB, Second Gen i7, Graphics ATI Mobility Radeon GDDR5 512MB, 6 GB DDR3 Mem.

I'm not sure what is, but Ubuntu 11.10 is a bit(alot) buggy. And I'm more so curious why this is... if my motehrboard architecture, Processor Architecture. Or am I using the wrong Ubuntu version. I downloaded Ubuntu 11.10, not sure which build... I can't even find that with this new setup.

Battery Guzzler.
gedit doesn't launch from terminal, 
install packages aren't launching correctly.
Mouse-tocuhpad is uber sensitive (but I think that's a driver issue)
And I could not launch a feedback report.

Considering Downgrading or "INSTALLing" 11.04 Or curious when is the next big release for Ubuntu. Thank you and have a nice day :)

Comment: i have read in some forum its because of buggy fan control in Ubuntu, though I'm not sure about the fact. I too have this problem...

Answer (score 1):

The most likely answer for your power consumption is that your ATI card isn't being powered off.  By default, both GPUs will be powered on and, on the hybrid laptop I've tested, this approximately doubles the idle power consumption.

It's likely that your laptop is supported by `vga_switcheroo`. If so, you can run

```
echo OFF | sudo tee /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

to turn off the unused ATI card.

I'm looking into automatically powering off the unused GPUs on boot in Ubuntu 12.04.